Unable to install local development server
I am unable to install the local development server
Tried out this command in the CLI
sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server

In the VS code I am getting the following error:
Error: C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules\@oclif\plugin-plugins\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest --omit dev --no-audit --loglevel=notice --no-fund
 »   exited with code 1
 »   Try this: Run with DEBUG=@oclif/plugin-plugins* to see debug output.


The Local Development Server functionality is due to be deprecated in favour of the new Local Dev functionality.

Migrate to the new Local Dev (Beta) experience before we eventually deprecate the LWC Local Development Server. Local Dev lets you quickly iterate on your Lightning web components in a real-time preview of your Lightning app or Experience Cloud Lightning Web Runtime site, without deploying code or manually refreshing the preview.

To enable this, you need to turn on this feature (it is off by default in orgs) by Navigating to Setup > Local Dev and enable 'Enable Local Dev'.
You can then run this via the commands sf lightning dev app or sf lightning dev site depending on whether you are wanting to preview a Lightning App or an LWR Site.
The additional flags that can be used with these commands are detailed in the documentation here: Test Components with Local Dev

As per this,


Installation of Nodejs software and disconnect from office network VPN (if connected).

Install node gyp by running
npm install -g node-gyp
In the command prompt or whatever command-line interface you use.

And then after that, you can run
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

And finally tried the below command it worked after 2 3 times.
sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server



Also, Refer to this: salesforce/lwc-dev-server installed successfully, Unable to install lwc-dev-server and Local server connection Issue with Lightning Web Component in VS Code

The above commands didn't work
